# Can't import ramda using Typescript and Aurelia

Tags: typescript, aurelia, jspm

Tinkering with Aurelia and wanting to use typescript. I ran `jspm install ramda` which seems to have worked just fine. Trying to use ramda like `import R from 'ramda'` and I get "Cannot find module 'ramda'" I'm sure I'm missing something really simple, but I can't see it.

Comment: you need a typescript definition file that describes that library, so typescript knows how it looks. do you have such a file in your project? it's most likely named ramda.d.ts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to install definition file for **ramda** ([typescript-ramda](https://github.com/donnut/typescript-ramda)) :

`typings install github:donnut/typescript-ramda --ambient --save`

Then, you need to configure your `tsconfig.json` in order to use the typings ([main.d.ts and browser.d.ts](https://github.com/typings/typings#maindts-and-browserdts)). Here is a possible configuration :

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "sourceMap": false
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typings/main.d.ts",
        "typings/main"
    ]
}
```

You should now be able to import ramda and use types defined in `ramda.d.ts` file :

```
import * as R from "ramda";

R.indexOf(10, [1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

Comment: What do you do if you want to work with something like `import always from 'ramda/src/always'`? (I mean specifically this as opposed to `import { always } from 'ramda'` in order to reduce the resulting payload size on client-side.)